# What does equals() function does in java?

Tags: java, string, palindrome

```
class ChkPalindrome
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String str, rev = "";
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 
      System.out.println("Enter a string:");
      str = sc.nextLine();
 
      int length = str.length();
 
      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         rev = rev + str.charAt(i);
 
      if (str.equals(rev))
         System.out.println(str+" is a palindrome");
      else
         System.out.println(str+" is not a palindrome");
 
   }
}
```

This a code for checking whether string is palindrome or not. In if statement, they have used .equals() function. In "**str**" variable I'm having user input string and in "**rev**" variable I'm having reverse string. So, if **.equals()** function checks whether string is similar or not, then how come string in "**str**" and string in "**rev**" will be same as "**rev**" has reversed string, and it will output that string is Palindrome?

Comment: each class can have or not have its own implementation of  `equals()` - documentation for the `String` one [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`equals` checks if two objects are logically equal.

A palindrome is a string that can be read the same way from front to back and from back to front. `rev` is `str` reversed. If you reverse a string and it's equal to the original string, it means that reading it backwards is the same as reading it forwards, and it's a palindrom.